# Correct hosts on Ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: 14.04, server, ipv6

VPS: Ubuntu 16.04 server, Nginx 1.10, PHP 7, MySQL 5.7.
I have IP4 and IPv6 address from my provider.
I have long been looking for an answer to the question: **Do I have to write IPv6 address in** `/etc/hosts`**?**

Now my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
188.225.32.275 server.domain.com server

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Change like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
188.225.32.275 server.domain.com server

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
2a04:6f00:4::bce1:444d server.domain.com server
```

Comment: Only if DNS doesn't work.

Comment: PTR Record have addresses ip4 and ipv6. So /etc/hosts must have ipv6 adress with FQDN (2a04:6f00:4::bce1:444d server.agestor.com server) too. I think it's logical.

Comment: Don't forget to configure your web server to also listen on IPv6 and that any IPv4 firewall rules have been ported to IPv6.